# Adafruit motor shield 1 and Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: motor, arduino-pro-mini, adafruit

Can any one tell me how to connect Adafruit motor shield v 1.0 with Arduino Pro Mini 5v 8 Mhz. Motor shield uses which pins as I want to replace my Arduino UNO to Pro Mini and need re-wiring. Tried it using jumper cables but did not work. Please help...

---

Product page [**here**](https://www.adafruit.com/products/81)
Manual [**here**](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-motor-shield.pdf)
Larger version of schematic [**here**](https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/009/769/original/mshieldv1-schem.png)

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: Providing links to ALL relevant gear would help. If it did not work "stand alone" with jumpers (eg NO Arduino) then you do not understand the shield pinouts.